# Stocking items inside an array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a textarea, and I want to stock the items of the textarea inside an array I created inside the app's state. Yesterday the code was running perfectly fine, but I think I just changed something out of the accident and there's this error.

the code collects the value inside the textarea and then uses a function to concat the array's items with the value written in the textarea whenever I click on the button. there's the app.js and the tasks.js which has the textarea and the button.

tasks.js:

```
import React from 'react'


class Tasks extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',            
        }
    }
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} ></textarea>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.value)}>Add task</button>
        </div>)

    }

}



export default Tasks
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tasks from './tasks.js';
import './App.css';




class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todolist: []
  }

  addData(val) {
    this.setState({todolist:this.state.todolist.concat(val)})
    console.log(this.state.todolist)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Tasks onClick={value => this.addData(value)} />

      </div>

    );
  }
}



export default App;
```

Instead of stocking the items, an error appears when I add the first array element. then, when I add the second element, the array stocks the first element. when I add the third element, the array now contains the first and the second element only. I know this because I've seen it in the console

Comment: What error is displayed? And if it was working and you believe you've broken it, I heavily suggest starting to use some version control software (e.g. git) to avoid this in future.

Comment: I've deleted the components I'm not using right now, and no error is being displayed anymore. however, still, on the first click, nothing adds up in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original question had an error which you since corrected with that edit. The only issue outstanding now is that [`setState` maybe an async operation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so you need to use its callback to check the state after its been updated.

```
addData(val) {
  this.setState({
    todolist: this.state.todolist.concat(val)
  }, () => console.log(this.state.todolist))
}
```

Comment: this works! however, I did not quite understand why :') would you please explain in more details?

Comment: If you google "setstate async" there are lots of articles about it that can explain it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need pass 'addData' from App to child as props then put it on handleChange
but you define it on Task as onClick event

add 
and on Task handleChange add
this.props.addData(e.target.value)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `addData` function inside an arrow function using the '(value)' instead  of passing it down to `<Tasks>`

instead of

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Tasks onClick={value => this.addData(value)} />

      </div>

    );
```

Just pass down a reference to the function addData, no need to call it or wrap it in an arrow function when you're just passing it down as a prop.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Tasks onClick={this.addData} />
      </div>

    );
```

The only problem is now because we removed the arrow function wrapping `this.addData(value)` you have lost your `this` binding. There are 2 ways to handle this.

#### Option 1

Bind the value of the `this` keyword inside addData by calling `.bind()` and passing in the current `this` context in the constructor lifecycle method.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        todolist: []
      }
      
      addData = this.addData.bind(this);
    }
  
    addData(val) {
      this.setState({todolist:this.state.todolist.concat(val)})
      console.log(this.state.todolist)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Tasks onClick={this.addData} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

Because arrow functions don't have an independent `this` context like normal functions we can change addData from a function declaration to an arrow function expression.

```
class App extends React.Component {

      state = {
        todolist: []
      }
  
    addData = (val) => {
      this.setState({todolist:this.state.todolist.concat(val)})
      console.log(this.state.todolist)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Tasks onClick={this.addData} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

You should look into the React Dev Tools extension for chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

It's much easier to inspect component state using React Dev Tools over console.log.

Answer (score 0):

as you know javascript runs in asynchronous way, so it doesn't wait `this.setState()` to complete and then pass to     `console.log()`.
you have to force it to wait until the state is set.

to do this you can use `async await` like :

```
async addData(val) {
    await this.setState({todolist:this.state.todolist.concat(val)})
    console.log(this.state.todolist)
  }
```